# double cannot be converted into integer

Tags: java, int, double

I have the following code

```
public ItemData findItem(Object searchterm) {
    if (searchterm instanceof Number) {
        int type = (int)((double) searchterm);
        return GETXmlParse.itemMap2.get(type);
    }
    return GETXmlParse.itemMap.get(searchterm.toString().toUpperCase());
}
```

When the code is executed it throws an error at:    int type = (int)((double) searchterm); , Saying a double cannot be converted to an integer.

Is there a way around to convert the double into the int?

Comment: you can also use Number.intValue() or Number.doubleValue()

Comment: What does *"convert the double into the int"* mean? Truncate? Round up? Round down?

Comment: and WHY do you want to convert a double into an int ? f.e. the value 3,4 would be represented as an int as 3. why first convert something into double, then into int

Comment: What is the class of searchterm? I've tried to reproduce your problem with Double searchterm, and the conversion always works without any exception.

Comment: The JLS defines conversion from double to int as a [Narrowing Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.3).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class abc {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        double a = 101.55;
        int i= (int)a;
        System.out.println(i);

    }   
}
```

try this.

Comment: public ItemData findItem(Double searchterm) {
    if (searchterm instanceof Number) {
        int type = (int)((double) searchterm);
        return GETXmlParse.itemMap2.get(type);
    }
    return GETXmlParse.itemMap.get(searchterm.toString().toUpperCase());
}

Answer (score 0):

You only know it is a Number so you have to cast it to a Number

```
if (searchterm instanceof Number) {
    int type = ((Number) searchterm).intValue();
```